# Cannot Locate gtk-builder-convert

Tags: pygtk, glade

all,

I have the latest version of PyGTK and Glade 3.8.0 installed on my Windows 7 system. However, I cannot locate gtk-builder-convert ANYWHERE, either on my system or online.

Where can I download gtk-builder-convert, and if it isn't an installer, where should I put the files for it? In my Python27 folder? In my Glade program files? Does it matter?

A previous question on here on this matter got me nowhere. The provided link does not contain the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glade 3.8.0 can save GtkBuilder files natively, so you don't generally need `gtk-builder-convert`.

But if you really need it for some reason, this appears to be what you're looking for: http://ossbuild.googlecode.com/svn-history/r937/trunk/Shared/Build/Windows/Win32/bin/gtk-builder-convert

Comment: In that case, how exactly do I save my file as an .xml. Do I just type in ".xml" on the end? (That's what I'm assuming)

Comment: Yes. But both Libglade and GtkBuilder formats are XML, so if you want GtkBuilder files (which you probably do, as that is the newer format that most people use) make sure you select that in the save dialog (it should be the default).

Also, from what I've noticed, people seem to save GtkBuilder files with a .ui extension rather than .xml, but it doesn't really matter.